# Using awk command to go through a text file and incrementing counters for morning, afternoon, and night sections of the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am using awk to go through a text file that has information of finished scripts then says complete (morning) then informaton of finished scripts then says complete (afternoon) then information of finished scripts then says complete (night).

I am trying to keep track of the finished scripts for each block.

The way I am doing it is...

```
awk '
    /Completed/ {next} //finished morning block

    /Finished/ {mornCount+=1} //count finishes in morning block

    /Completed/ {next}

    /Finished/ {afterCount+=1}

    /Completed/ {exit}

    /Finished/ {nightCount+=1}

    END{ 
        print "procedures completed this morning: " mornCount 
        print "procedures completed this afternoon: " afterCount
        print "procedures completed at night: " nightCount
    } 
' file.txt
```

However the values I get for morn, after, and night is the same.

```
start 
start 
start 
Finished
Finished
Finished
Completed
start 
start 
Finished
Finished 
Completed 
start 
Finished 
Complete
```

so I would want 3, 2, and 1 as my output - finishes for (morning, afternoon, and night)

Comment: are you confined to awk?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic No I am not, however when I just did it for morning it worked perfectly. So I was thinking adding afternoon and night it would also work.

Comment: Put an example of your expected input and output. Also why do you have multiple blocks for completed, the last one will never be executed as the first skips all future commands.

Comment: well can you post an input example of the file you're parsing?

Comment: I cannot because its for work. But I can give an example....  start  start  start  finish  finish  finish complete  start start finish finish complete  start finish complete so I would want 3, 2, and 1 as my output finishes for (morning, afternoon, and night)

Comment: Put the example in your question with formatting

Comment: @alan are there supposed to be newlines between them ?

Comment: For some reason when I do the two spaces it doesnt format for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
awk 'BEGIN{split("morning afternoon night",a)}
     /Finished/{x++}
     /Completed/{print a[++y]":"x;x=0}' file
```

BEGIN block executes at the start of the script.
The split just creates an array like

```
a[1] = morning 
a[2] = afternoon 
a[3] = night
```

x is incremented every time Finished is seen
When completed is seen, y is incremented and value from that position in `a` is printed with the value in x.
x is reset
repeat

---

Output from your example

```
morning:3
afternoon:2
night:1
```

Comment: Can you try to explain your code? And ty for your answer

Comment: @Alan this is exactly the right answer, you should click on the accept check mark unless there's something else...

Answer (score 2):

This should work even when the sections have zero finished tasks:

```
awk -v FS="\n" -v RS="complete" '
    BEGIN { morn = 0; after = 0; night = 0 }    
    NR == 1 { for( i = 1; i < NF; i++) { if ($i ~ "finish") { morn++ } } }
    NR == 2 { for( i = 1; i < NF; i++) { if ($i ~ "finish") { after++ } } }
    NR == 3 { for( i = 1; i < NF; i++) { if ($i ~ "finish") { night++ } } }
    END { 
        print "procedures completed this morning: " morn 
        print "procedures completed this afternoon: " after
        print "procedures completed at night: " night
}' file.txt
```

Comment: what is the (!xxxxCount) condition for?

Comment: what I was thinking is if the condition is for it being 0 or not what if there are 0 procedures that run in the morning. Then all the numbers willl be shifted

Comment: mhmm interesting the morn and night numbers are correct but afternoon is 0

Comment: Im using a file from work so I cant show you it. But your other idea for the script worked so Im trying to see why this one wouldnt

Comment: It should be stated that this is gawk-specific due to multi-char RS.

Answer (score 2):

TXR Lisp:

```
(mapdo (do put-line `@1: @2`)
       '#"morning afternoon night"
       [mapcar (op count-if (op match-regex @1 #/Finished/))
               (partition (get-lines)
                          (op where (op match-regex @1 #/Complete/)))])

$ txr count.tl < data.txt
morning: 3
afternoon: 2
night: 1
```

Get the lines of the file as a list of strings. Partition the list into a list of lists, breaking it where it matches `/Complete`.  Then count the occurrences of matches for `/Finished/` in every piece, and map the counts together with the section names through a function that converts them pairwise into output.

The above linear description of the process can be expressed via a rearrangement to a functional pipeline via the `opip` macro. Since that returns a function, it has to be called; to clarify that, why not employ rarely-used `call` function rather than the syntax `[pipeline]`.

```
(let ((pipeline (opip (get-lines)
                      (partition @1 (op where (op match-regex @1 #/Complete/)))
                      (mapcar (op count-if (op match-regex @1 #/Finished/)))
                      (mapdo (do put-line `@1: @2`) '#"morning afternoon night"))))
  (call pipeline))
```

Without the temporary `pipeline` variable, and `call` replaced by square brackets:

```
[(opip (get-lines)
       (partition @1 (op where (op match-regex @1 #/Complete/)))
       (mapcar (op count-if (op match-regex @1 #/Finished/)))
       (mapdo (do put-line `@1: @2`) '#"morning afternoon night"))]
```

A solution in the TXR text extraction pattern language, with touch of Lisp:

```
@(collect)
@  (collect)
@{f /Finished.*/}
@  (until)
@/Complete.*/
@  (end)
@(end)
@(output)
morning: @(length [f 0])
afternoon: @(length [f 1])
night: @(length [f 2])
@(end)

$ txr count.txr data.txt 
morning: 3
afternoon: 2
night: 1
```

With section names encoded as list and traversed:

```
@(collect)
@  (collect)
@{f /Finished.*/}
@  (until)
@/Complete.*/
@  (end)
@(end)
@(bind sec #"morning afternoon night")
@(output)
@  (repeat :vars (f))
@sec: @(length f)
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Note: `:vars (f)` is needed because the `@(output)` processor does not traverse Lisp to look for variable references, so it cannot automatically see `f` the way t sees `sec`. There is no good way to do that since Lisp code can express free variable references that `@(output)` *shouldn't* see.